# swift: image in collection

Tags: ios, swift

I have collectionView with image in cell. I want to show image in some cells.

I use this code:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 7
}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

        if (indexPath.row == 2 && indexPath.section == 6) || (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {
            cell.cover.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.cover.image = UIImage(named: "2.png")
        }
}
```

But when I scroll my collectionView image not showing in some different cells.

Comment: The if statement makes it so that the image doesn't show up in certain cells. It is not quite clear what the problem is.

Comment: Because of cell reuse, you need to make sure to set `cell.cover.isHidden = false` in the `else` clause, or your image might be hidden due to the stale value hanging around from a previously used cell.  You should set `cell.cover.image = nil` in the then clause.

Answer (score 2):

All other answers are just workarounds. The real problem is that your `MasterViewCell` doesn't implemented `func prepareForReuse()` where you should prepare cell before reuse (in your case unhide `cover` view). If you implementing custom cell you always need to override this method. See the [documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse)

Answer (score 0):

```
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell
    cell.cover.image = nil

    if (indexPath.row == 2 && indexPath.section == 6) || (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.cover.isHidden = true
    } else {
        cell.cover.isHidden = false
        cell.cover.image = UIImage(named: "2.png")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with this.

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

    if (indexPath.row == 2 && indexPath.section == 6) || (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.cover.isHidden = true
    } else {
        cell.cover.isHidden = false
        cell.cover.image = UIImage(named: "2.png")
    }
```

}

It is happening because of the collection view cell reusability.